# Return search results from only 2 document libraries

Tags: 2010, enterprise-search

How to configure search to return results from only two document libraries in a subsite? Whenever I type a keyword in that subsite's search box, it should always return results from the 2 document libraries created in that subsite.

Comment: Path can work, but using Content Types in this case makes it SO much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint Central Admin, you can create a **Scope** that can be applied to particular search facilities.  A scope can include/exclude URls that you define so for example, you could create a scope that only includes the URL for your two document libraries and apply it to your search box. Note, you should only include the URL to the library such as `http://siteCollection/subSite/library/` and not a URL that includes view information such as `http://siteCollection/subSite/library/AllDocuments.aspx`.

You can configure a scope under General Application Settings > Search > Farm Search Administration > Search Service > Scopes.   Create the scope with a name you like, then add some rules.  In your case, you would want to create a **Folder** rule specifying your library name and set the behaviour to **Include**.  You have to repeat this per library.

Once you have created the rules, run a full crawl and apply the scope to your search box using the scopes name.

For more information see [this Microsoft article](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Define-scopes-for-searches-65c26a72-f3d3-42ba-8027-1bf7260b6acf) or [this blog post](http://www.surfray.com/blog/2013/06/17/how-to-configure-scopes-in-sharepoint-2010/).

Answer (score 0):

Add `(site:UrlOfLibrary1 OR site:UrlOfLibrary2)` as additional query terms

Comment: Hmm, tried to delete my own answer and yours got deleted. Sorry about that :)

Comment: Where should I write this query terms?

Comment: Sorry should be site:

Comment: By this URL you mean search scopes?

Comment: The tutorial at `http://tutorial.programming4.us/windows_server/SharePoint-2010---Configuring-Search-Settings-and-the-User-Interface---Web-Parts-(part-1).aspx` shows how to configure the Search interface. In part 2 it shows the 'Additional query terms'. UrlOfLibrary1 (and 2) is the real url of the list like `http://intranet.contoso.com/sites/mysite/Documents`